# Responsive background image with responsive height and width

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get these divs to be at max 500px by 500px. Even setting the max-width and max-height properties, it still takes up the whole page plus some height wise. I want the background images to be responsive and maintain their aspect ratio. I read that if you divide the height by the width then multiply to 100, you get the percentage to use as the padding-top property. In my case 500 / 500 is 1 and multiplied by 100 is well, 100%. Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
}

div {
  width: 40%;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding-top: 100%;

  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/500x500);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;

  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;

  margin: 2.5%;

  float: left;
}
```

Comment: You can set the background size to pixels or use one of the other options for this.  see background-size options here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to use pixels. I want relative units (em, %).

Comment: Which is why I suggested looking at the link I posted and using relative units

Answer (score 1):

You have `max-width: 500px`, and then you overwrite it with the `background-size: cover`. If you want to use the `background-size: cover`, you should put a second `div` within that `div` and use that `background-size: cover` style on that nested `div` so it covers the parent `div`, which has a max width of 500px.

For example:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>

.parent {max-width: 500px}
.child {background-size: cover; //include image}
```

Did not test the code, but you get the gist of it.

Comment: My pleasure. You should make sure you understand what is going on for future reference.